# how to get data from multiple model in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I've a problem in customize view in my application that upload images 
i have three models

```
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Picture> picture{ get; set; }
```

and second

```
    public int MacId { get; set; }
    public string machine { get; set; }
```

and third

```
public int PicId { get; set; }
    public string PicPath { get; set; }             
    public int MacId { get; set; }
    public int EmpId { get; set; }  

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
```

and i want to make it show picture of mac and who is the employee who take it ?

Comment: You could use a view model. Basically your controller action will query your DAL and build a view model that will be passed to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Create New Model With the neccesary properties you want to bind to your view.

for eg:

```
class newModelName
{
     public Model1TypeName model1 {get ; set; }
     public Model2TypeName model2 {get ; set; }
     public Model3TypeName model3 {get ; set; }
}
```

Now you can bind this new model to your view which will have all necessary information from all the three views.

Comment: i try it but when i use it to make CRUD it appear something wrong ,so when i call model1 for example it refuse to bind or read data in it